# How can I determine the invoking user in an Apple installer postinstall script

Tags: macos, install

I want to build an apple installer .pkg where I run a postinstall script after the files have been copied by the installer. The script is run and everything works perfect except that all the commands in the script are run as root.

The question is, how can I determine the id of the user who actually invoked the installer.

```
who -m
```

returns the invoking user when I run the script on the command line with `sudo`. But it returns `root` when I run it in the installer.

Is there any way to get the "actual user"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some testing, I believe I have found that one of the best options for this is

```
INSTALLER_USER=$(stat -f '%Su' $HOME)
```

I have found that the `$HOME` environmental variable of the user installing the package is passed through, even after elevating for `Installer.app` or using the `installer` command.

The previous answers are assuming some things about the environment that may not always be true.

For example `CONSOLE_USER=$(ps aux | grep console | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f1)` does not work in there are multiple users logged in, as may be the case in a computer lab environment.

As for `ps aux | grep "CoreServices/Installer" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1;}'`; this only works if the user is actually running  `Installer.app` and would not apply to someone running it with the `installer` command in a shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine who owns the "console" and invoke `sudo -u` command.

Something like this:

```
CONSOLE_USER=$(ps aux | grep console | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f1)
sudo -u $CONSOLE_USER COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE
```

Comment: I now do something similar and grep for the user who started the installer process
    `ps aux | grep "CoreServices/Installer" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1;}'`
But is this really the "way to go"?

Comment: Solved my problem and seems to be more stable than my solution, since the name of the installer is not involved. Thanks a lot!