# How can I return the logged in user from inside a pkg which is running as root?

Tags: bash, launchd, user-account, root, package-management

I'm using the [Packages app](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create an installer which includes, among other things, a launchd job.

The postinstall Bash script needs to target the logged in user as follows:

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/$UID ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myproduct.plist
```

The problem is that $UID returns 0 when run from within the package.

The following tweak works as expected on my machine but the target deployment users don't use 501 but mobile accounts so the UID differs with each AD account

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myproduct.plist
```

I've tried all sorts of things:

```
$SUDO_USER
$LOGNAME
$(who -m | awk '{print $1;})
$(logname 2>/dev/null || $SUDO_NAME)
```

All return the 0/root user.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269066/how-can-i-obtain-the-full-name-of-the-currently-logged-in-user-via-terminal-when) seems to work, on my machine, when run it Terminal after sudo su. But, as I don't understand the /dev/console bit (or the %Su parameter), is it 100% reliable?

```
id -P $(stat -f%Su /dev/console) | cut -d : -f 3
```

Comment: Probably a bit late as you have written the app but I think the Apple way is to use SMJobBless https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589548/understanding-priviledged-helper-tools-in-osx so everything is inside the main app's bundle

Comment: For future browsers, there is a similar question and answers at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/144159.

Answer (score 3):

The `stat` command is run with the `-f%Su` parameter, where `-f` means that an output format follows, and `%Su` means that it should output (`%`) a string (`S`) which is the user ID (`u`) of the file's owner.

Your command then provides the username to the `id` command in order to get to the username - which seems to be a way roundabout way of getting that, as you could just have asked `stat` for it initially like this:

```
stat -f%Uu /dev/console
```

Doing it like this means you won't have to call `id` and `cut`.

The `stat` command is completely reliable in returning the user id/name of the owner of the `/dev/console` file (or actually character device). The question is just whether this user is the one, you're looking for. In general, it will work - but you might see a different behaviour than you're expecting when users are also logged in via Remote Desktop. In that case, the last login performed will be returned (i.e. when multiple user's are logged in at the same time).

There's also a different method of getting the currently logged in user by asking the System Configuration Daemon:

```
scutil <<< "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ { print $3 }'
```

The difference between the two is that looking at `/dev/console` cannot distinguish between root being logged in (i.e. root logins have been enabled by the user), or the computer being sat at the login window - both will return root as the owner of the file. Whether or not this is a problem for you depends on your specific use-case.

Comment: Super answer @jkseogaard thank you. Returning to `man stat` with your answer as a reference also helped me decode what I'd already read! (% is rather hidden). This PKG will probably be deployed by Jamf so I'm really not sure if `/dev/console` will work reliably but I'm about to find out!